# TwoWay Databinding Not Updating Reference

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a custom User control (I'll call it Tree here) which defines a `DependecyProperty` for an `IEnumerable` collection.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(RadTreeView));
```

I have a sort routine which creates a new instance of the collection.

```
ItemsSource = ItemsSource.Cast<object>().OrderBy(x => TypeHelper.GetPropertyValue(x, SortField.Path), SortField.GetComparer()).ToList();
```

The UI is updated properly with the sorted Tree, however, since the sort function creates a new collection reference the source DataContext now has an old reference to the collection.

In the UserControl which consumes the Tree control, I have set the `ItemsSource` binding to be `TwoWay` but that is not working as I would have expected it to, automatically updating the source binding with the new reference.

```
<Tree ItemsSource="{Binding Organizations, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I've also tried explicitly updating the source binding after I sort the collection

```
GetBindingExpression(ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateSource();
```

How can I update the source DataContext reference when it is changed by a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This will be a proxy source the sits between your real items and the source you bind to the tree.